# Which javascript library is using by Creditkarma for showing score?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Any similar library would also be appreciated.

Comment: assuming it is javascript running it, why don't you log into their site and [inspect the elements in question.](https://ibb.co/ce8GN6)

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. It's a tool/product recommendation question. And as for what another site is using? That would just be guesswork, but even if someone did know: it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved it by using [gauge.js](http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/)

As shown ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may check this and modify to support your requirements

https://github.com/soundar24/roundSlider

Comment: Yes but i want to find exact library first ...